# How do you burn a CD in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, cd-burning

How do you burn a CD within iTunes?

I want to be able to burn some music to a CD, but I just can't find the option.

Answer (score 4):

Select a bunch of songs, pick **File → New Playlist from Selection**, name it, and pick **File → Burn Playlist to Disc**.

Comment: The easier way to do this is to create the playlist first without any songs, then you have the ability to drag songs into the playlist, this is much better if you have to scroll through thousands of songs, or use search.

Comment: Where is this function within iTunes 11?
I don't see this menu entry.

Comment: The first part is now **File → New → Playlist from Selection**, and the second is still **File → Burn Playlist to Disc**.

Answer (score 2):

As Sören says, you cannot arbitrarily pick a selection of songs and burn them in one step, you can only burn a playlist.  This does give you the opportunity to ensure that the total length will fit on your disc at least, but it does seem a little pointless.

Comment: It's similarly impossible to double-click on a song and have just that song play: I have to create a playlist with just one song *every single time* to do so (or manage my "One Song" playlist by adding the one I want to hear and deleting whatever was in there before). iTunes is very playlist-centric in a way that makes some things much harder than it seems like they should be.

Comment: Very true, and yet in others it's also very single track centric, especially where is concerns albums that have multiple artists - sure we've all have the "12 albums of the same name" problem before now.  Split personality, I'm hoping for an overhaul soon that concentrates on Music, and moves the Apps/books/Sync stuff etc out somewhere else to help them concentrate on what it should be used for!